# LINQ group by one field and sort by another

Tags: c#, linq, microsoft-metro

I'm trying to create a grouped ListView for a Windows 8 Metro style app. Linq is a bit new to me. I understand the basics and I'm familiar with mySQL but I'm struggling with the syntax of this one.

I have a class that contains (amongst other things) a string "Date" and an int "epochTime". The date string is a representation of the epochTime but in the format "April, 23rd 2012" for example - ignoring the hour of the event.

So I want to group by the date string and sort the groups and the contents of the groups by the epoch time. The closest I've come so far is this

```
var result =
                from fixture in items
                group fixture by new { fixture.Date, fixture.epochTime } into g
                orderby g.Key.epochTime
                select g;
```

But this groups on date and epochTime so I get events that are on the same day but a different time in groups of their own. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks is advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>Well it may not be *guaranteed* by linq but</strike> you could try ordering the list before grouping:

```
from fixture in items.OrderBy(i => i.epochTime)
            group fixture by fixture.Date into g
            select g;
```

**EDIT** According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534501.aspx) the order is preserved after grouping:

> The IGrouping objects are yielded in an order based on
>   the order of the elements in source that produced the first key of
>   each IGrouping. Elements in a grouping are yielded in
>   the order they appear in source.

Answer (score 0):

Can do:

```
from fixture in items 
group fixture by fixture.Date into g 
orderby g.First().eepochTime
select g;
```